# How to hide entire row if one or two fields are empty Django

Tags: django, django-models

How can I hide an entire row if one or more specific fields are empty? For example, I have a django query set up so that I can get a total profit from items in the inventory manager. The way that I have that written is like:

**html**

```
{% extends 'portal/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Inventory{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
           <form class="d-flex" role="search" action="/search" method="get">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
           <a class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" href="/newitem" type="button">Input New Purchase</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <table class="table table-striped">
       <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Breakdown</th>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Total Profit</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       {% for inventory in inventory %}
       <tr>
        <td><a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' href=''>View Breakdown</a>
        <td>{{inventory.id}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.product}}</td>
        <td>{{ inventory.Calculate_profit }}</td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def profitsperitem(request):
    inventory = Inventory.objects.all().order_by('id')

    return render(request, 'portal/profitsperitem.html', {"inventory": inventory})
```

**models.py**

```
@property
    def Calculate_profit(self):
        soldfor = Inventory.objects.filter(soldprice=self.soldprice).aggregate(Sum('soldprice'))['soldprice__sum'] or 0.00 
        paidfor = Inventory.objects.filter(paid=self.paid).aggregate(Sum('paid'))['paid__sum'] or 0.00 
        shipfor = Inventory.objects.filter(shipcost=self.shipcost).aggregate(Sum('shipcost'))['shipcost__sum'] or 0.00

        totalprofit = soldfor - paidfor - shipfor

        return totalprofit
```

As long as the model fields `soldprice` , `paid` , and `shipcost` are all filled out on every row in the database, I can get the results no problem. I get an error if `soldprice` or `shipcost` are null or none, so when there is nothing added to database. If one row does not have `soldprice` or `shipcost` set, none of the results can be viewed as this error pops up: "TypeError at /profitsperitem
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'"

**My question is how can I hide the entire row if either or both `soldprice` and/or `shipcost` are empty?**

Comment: You can use `if statement` in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Tho filter all rows with any of the two fields beeing `null`/`None` use a query like this

```py
from django.db.models import Q

@login_required(login_url="/login")
def profitsperitem(request):
    inventory = Inventory.objects.filter(
        Q(soldprice__isnull = False) | Q(shipcost__isnull = False)
    ).order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'portal/profitsperitem.html', {"inventory": inventory})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update the view like this

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def profitsperitem(request):
    inventory = Inventory.objects.filter(soldprice__isnull = False, shipcost__isnull = False).order_by('id')

    return render(request, 'portal/profitsperitem.html', {"inventory": inventory})
```

Comment: This will only hide rows where both fields are `null`/`None`

Answer (score 0):

```
    {% for inventory in inventory %}
        {% if inventory.Calculate_profit %}
           <tr>
            <td><a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' href=''>View Breakdown</a>
            <td>{{inventory.id}}</td>
            <td>{{inventory.product}}</td>
            <td>{{ inventory.Calculate_profit }}</td>
           </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

you can print row only if you have calculate price.

```
if(soldfor is not None and paidfor is not None and shipfor is not None )
  totalprofit = soldfor - paidfor - shipfor
else totalprofit =None
```

Also You can check if Calculate profit has some value